# How to add a blank space when replacing a line in a file

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment. I am very new to Python and Programming in general.

My assignment is to create a menu with a list of friend's names. Then I should be able to print the names, add a name, change a name, and erase a name. I am working on the change a name. My problem is when I change a name it is adding a new space after every name. I only want to add a space after the new name. I think the problem lies in the definition of replace_line.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*              #imports the Tkinter (GUI) library
master = Tk()                   # Creates a Tk root widget to initialize Tkinter


names_list = Listbox(master)                  # Creates the listbox
names_list.pack()

names_list.insert(0,"Print List of Names")
names_list.insert(1,"Add Name")      #This populates the listbox with the different    options
names_list.insert(2,"Change Name")
names_list.insert(3,"Remove Name")
names_list.insert(4,"Quit")

def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):         # This creates the function that  will erase names
lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
lines[line_num] = text
out = open(file_name, 'w')
out.writelines('\n'.join(lines))          # Problem Here, adding a new line to every element
out.close()

def CurSelect(evt):                   # defines the CurSelect function that will print out the the value latter selected in the listbox
value=str((names_list.get(names_list.curselection())))

if value =="Print List of Names":           # What to do if  "Print List of Names" is selected
  names = open("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Classes/GPC/Intro to Comp Sci/Python Name Book Assignment/Names.txt",'r')
  for name in names:         #reads names as a list line by line istead of all on one line
    print(name)
  names.close
else:
    if value == "Add Name":           # What to do if "Add Name" is selected
     names = open("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Classes/GPC/Intro to Comp Sci/Python Name Book Assignment/Names.txt",'a')
     new_name=input("Type the name you would like to add and press enter")          # This creates a variable that is passes to file.write for appending
     names.write(new_name)
     names.write("\n")                   # This adds a new line after appending the new_name variable
     names.close
    else:
        if value == "Change Name":           # What to do if "Change Name" is selected
            names = open("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Classes/GPC/Intro to Comp Sci/Python Name Book Assignment/Names.txt",'r')
            phrase = input("Enter name to change")         # Looks for the name to change
            for line in names:           # Looks for the line number that the name to change is on
                if phrase in line:
                   with open("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Classes/GPC/Intro to Comp Sci/Python Name Book Assignment/Names.txt",'r') as myFile:
                    for num, line in enumerate(myFile, 0):
                        if phrase in line:              # Actually replaces the name with a new name entered by the user
                         phrase_change = input("Enter name to change to")
                         replace_line("C:/Users/Jonathan/Desktop/Classes/GPC/Intro to Comp Sci/Python Name Book Assignment/Names.txt", num, phrase_change)


names_list.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelect)       #binds the selection in the listbox to the Curselect function


master.mainloop()                            # Tkinter Event Loop: make the window actually appear
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines returned by `file.readlines` already contain a trailing `'\n'`, so you just need to add `'\n'` to the text you're replacing:

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as fin, open(file_name, 'w') as out:
        lines = fin.readlines()
        lines[line_num] = text + '\n'             #This should contain a '\n'
        out.writelines(lines)
```

Always use `with` statement for handling file, it will make sure that the file is closed as soon as the `with` block exits, even when an exception occurs.

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> It is good practice to use the `with` keyword when dealing with file
>   objects. This has the advantage that the file is properly closed after
>   its suite finishes, even if an exception is raised on the way.